# Powershell Compare two directories files (Name and Hash). Report if the name is only in one dir but ignore it for the hash check

Tags: powershell, compare

I have two directories.  One is the Source one was a Copy of the source that could be changed.  I need to compare the two directories to find if there are:

1. New files in either directory
2. Existing files that have changed in the Copy only.

I created the following and it shows me all that but it flags the changed files from both sides. Giving me two results for the same file.  I want to filter already compared files so that only one instance shows.

Here is what I have

```
$VDrive = "C:\Temp"
$Set = "GroupA"
function check-hash{
$DefaultDir = "$VDrive\Default\Files"
$SetDir = "$VDrive\$Set\Files"
    
    $SetArray = @()
    $SetArray = @((Get-ChildItem -File -Path $SetDir -Recurse) | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "Thumbs.db"}| 
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
        h = (Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm SHA1).Hash
        n = $_.Name
        s = $_.Length
        fn = $_.fullname
        }})
   
    $DefaultArray = @()
    $DefaultArray = @((Get-ChildItem -File -Path $DefaultDir -Recurse) | Where-Object { $_-notmatch "Thumbs.db"}| 
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
        h = (Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm SHA1).Hash
        n = $_.Name
        s = $_.Length
        fn = $_.fullname
        }})

    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $DefaultArray  -DifferenceObject $SetArray -Property n,h,s -PassThru | ForEach-Object {
        $Vfile = $($_.fn)
        #if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "==" ) { "===$Vfile in passed Hash Check" } 
        if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" ) { "Hash Update $Vfile - Default file Different" }
        if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" )  { "Hash Delete $Vfile - In Set not Default" }
        }           
}
check-hash
```

This returns <= and => for any file that is different.  I just want one but I need to check both ways.

Comment: What's the output suppose to look like?

Comment: I need to know if there are files that don't exist in one directory or the other and which ones have changed from the Source.  I get that but I am trying to automate a process and I don't want it returning the same file twice (ex. Source\File.txt => and Copy\File.txt <=).  I am trying to filter one side while still seeing the ones that are unique.

Comment: My thought was to run the Compare against Name and then if == run it against the Hash. I just can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "new file" ? a hash that is unique in either folder or a filename that is unique ?

Comment: I file that is in one directory but not the other.  So it would be a null on one side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it, it's more code than what you already have but I believe should do what you're looking for.

The firsts steps are mainly the same, gather all SHA1 hashes from both folders and construct a list of objects.

Then, on the first loop over the *"difference folder"* (this would be the **Copy folder**), filter by **Unique files based on it's hashes compared to the reference folder** and **files where the Name of the file exists in the reference folder but it's hash has changed** (this would meet the **condition 2** of your question).

Lastly, the second loop over the *"reference folder"* to get the unique files of this collection **based on the file hashes**.

The `$result` collection would be an array of objects with a newly added property `Status` to help identify if the file has changed or if it's unique.

```sh
$result = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()

$sb = {
    process {
        if($_.Name -eq 'Thumbs.db') { return }

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            h  = (Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm SHA1).Hash
            n  = $_.Name
            s  = $_.Length
            fn = $_.fullname
        }
    }
}

$refFiles  = Get-ChildItem 'path/to/reference/folder' -Recurse -File | & $sb
$diffFiles = Get-ChildItem 'path/to/difference/folder' -Recurse -File | & $sb

foreach($file in $diffFiles) {
    # this file exists on both folders, skip it
    if($file.h -in $refFiles.h) { continue }
    # this file exists on reference folder but has changed
    if($file.n -in $refFiles.n) {
        $file.PSObject.Properties.Add(
            [psnoteproperty]::new('Status', 'Changed in Ref')
        )
        $result.Add($file)
        continue
    }
    # this file does not exist on reference folder
    # based on previous conditions
    $file.PSObject.Properties.Add(
        [psnoteproperty]::new('Status', 'Unique in Diff')
    )
    $result.Add($file)
}

foreach($file in $refFiles) {
    # this file is unique in reference folder, rest of the files
    # not meeting this condition can be ignored since we're
    # interested only in files on reference folder that are unique
    if($file.h -notin $diffFiles.h) {
        $file.PSObject.Properties.Add(
            [psnoteproperty]::new('Status', 'Unique in Ref')
        )
        $result.Add($file)
    }
}

$result | Format-Table
```

Comment: Thank you, Santiago.  I was working on something similar based on another thread I found but I like this from a standpoint of being able to use it in a few different ways!  I will try and incorporate it when I am back in the office.

Comment: @Eubs my pleasure, normally you could use `Compare-Object` for this kind of things but in this particular case I did not see a way around using it. Constructing the result manually seemed a better approach.

Comment: I was working with an idea from an answer in thi post for -Powershell Compare-Object with Hash only pass $_.SideIndicator and not $_.path $_.hash.  by @Theo.  
He created three separate lists and I think I can then compare the => and <= lists to get what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with Compare-object and I was able to get it to work by creating a sub array.  Thanks to a post by @Theo.  The answer from @Santiago Squarzon works, but I was still curious if I could do it.

```
$VDrive = "C:\Temp"
$Set = "GroupA"
function check-hash{
$DefaultDir = "$VDrive\Default\Files"
$SetDir = "$VDrive\$Set\Files"
    
    $SetArray = @()
    $SetArray = @((Get-ChildItem -File -Path $SetDir -Recurse) | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "Thumbs.db"}| 
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
        h = (Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm SHA1).Hash
        n = $_.Name
        pn = $($_.fullname).Replace("C:\Temp\$Set", "")
        fn = $_.fullname
        }})
   
    $DefaultArray = @()
    $DefaultArray = @((Get-ChildItem -File -Path $DefaultDir -Recurse) | Where-Object { $_-notmatch "Thumbs.db"}| 
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
        h = (Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm SHA1).Hash
        n = $_.Name
        pn = $($_.fullname).Replace("C:\Temp\Default", "")
        fn = $_.fullname
        }})

    Write-host "Comparing..."
    $compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $DefaultArray  -DifferenceObject $SetArray -Property h,pn -IncludeEqual -PassThru | Select-Object n,pn,SideIndicator,fn
    $filecomp = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $DefaultArray  -DifferenceObject $SetArray -Property pn -IncludeEqual -PassThru | Select-Object n,pn,SideIndicator,fn
        $doSet = $compare | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' }
        $doDefault = $compare | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' }
        $foSet = $filecomp | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' }
        $foDefault = $filecomp | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } 

        if ($foSet) {
            Write-Host "File Delta from Default"  -ForegroundColor Yellow
            $foSet | Format-Table -AutoSize
            }
    
        if ($foDefault) {
            Write-Host "File Delta From Set"  -ForegroundColor Green
            $foDefault | Format-Table -AutoSize
            }
               
#####   Try comparing doSet and doDefault ############################################
    $Dcomp = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $doSet  -DifferenceObject $doDefault -Property pn -IncludeEqual -PassThru | Select-Object n,pn,SideIndicator,fn
        $DcompSwim = $Dcomp | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '==' }
    
        if ($DcompSwim) {
            Write-Host "Hash Delta from Default"  -ForegroundColor Cyan
            $DcompSwim | Format-Table -AutoSize
            }
    
}
check-hash
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If I want to compare two directories I would like to consider the file's relative path.
For example if I have a clone of two directories and someone moves a file to another directory under that directory hierarchy then they would not be the a clone anymore , the file exists in both directories but the relative path is different.
So my approach to this problem would be to not just find the hash in both directories but also to compare the relative path.
The differences would be stored on variables $onlyinfolder1 and $onlyinfolder2.

```
$folder1 = "\\Oldfileserver\departments\HR"
$folder2 = "\\Newfileserver\departments\HR"
$hash1 = Get-ChildItem $folder1 -Recurse -Force | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5
$hash2 = Get-ChildItem $folder2 -Recurse -Force | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5
$onlyinfolder1=@()
$onlyinfolder2=@()
foreach ($hash in $hash1) {
    $match = $hash2 | Where-Object { ($_.Hash -eq $hash.Hash) -and ($_.Path.replace($folder2,"") -eq $hash.Path.replace($folder1,""))}
    if ($match) {
        #Write-Host "File $($hash.Path) exists in both folders and is identical." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    } else {
        $onlyinfolder1+=$hash
        Write-Host "File $($hash.Path) $($hash.Hash) exists only in $folder1." -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
foreach ($hash in $hash2) {
    $match = $hash1 | Where-Object { $_.Hash -eq $hash.Hash -and $_.Path.replace($folder1,"") -eq $hash.Path.replace($folder2,"")}
    if (!$match) {
        $onlyinfolder2+=$hash
        Write-Host "File $($hash.Path) $($hash.Hash) exists only in $folder2." -ForegroundColor Magenta
    }
}
Write-Host "There are $($onlyinfolder1.count) unique files in $folder1"
Write-Host "There are $($onlyinfolder2.count) unique files in $folder2"
```